# How to run all node.js on startup

Tags: raspbian, pi-3

I want to run all node.js scripts in some folder on startup (in perfect case, running some npm script (I think the thing i run by `npm run someScript` by this) in all folders in some specific folder). Is this possible without making some Java program?
THX

Answer (score 2):

You can probably use Cron to do that. You can read the documentation here: https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/linux/usage/cron.md. You can enter this to edit crontab:

```
crontab -e
```

Select Nano or any editor you're comfortable with and add a line like this:

```
@reboot npm run /home/pi/somescript
```

I recommend you read the documentation first, though.

Comment: Ok, but my goal is to just put the app in some folder and it will run on reboot without doing anything else.

Comment: @doc.Chocholoušek That would work too you would just need to replace /home/pi/somescript with the location of your script.

Comment: Ok, but still I need to write the command to terminal. And by more actions to do, there is bigger chance that I will forget one of them.

Comment: @doc.Chocholoušek You just need to do this once as long as you don't keep changing the directory or filename of your script.

Comment: Yes, but by adding more and more apps, I need to write it to console again and again (I need this for discord bots and I am making also really small bots just for fun and I don't want to solve why it isn't working when i forget to start the cron task).

Comment: @doc.Chocholoušek Oh, are you familiar with python? If you are an easy solution would be to create a simple script to append the command to the crontab. Though it still might cause you some trouble. How many scripts do you think you might have? Also, another solution to this issue would be to create a python script to check if each node.js script has an equivalent crontab entry, this would make debugging much easier

Comment: I did not learn phyton, but friend is saying, that it is almost same as c#, so I think can learn it very quickly. But I already know how to program in Java. Also I got idea that I can run the phyton/java program on startup and using it start all node.js files but idk if it is good idea.

Comment: @doc.Chocholoušek Actually I didn't think of that. But creating a Java Program to start up your Scripts is a pretty good idea. I'd do it in Python but I'm sure you can make it work for Java too. Then you'd only have to put one entry in the crontab.

Comment: Ok, I will try to make it and post here if it works.